# In Firebase Crashlytics, Where can I see user ID in the Reported Crashes?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

Firebase Crashlytics has a feature for customizing crash reports. In my case, I'm reporting the internal user ID so that I can pull up more information to debug the issue.

I'm not able to see the user ID anywhere in the Firebase Crashlytics tab.

I call this in

`Application.onCreate()`

```
Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(uid);
```

Comment: In the _Data_ tab of the Firebase Console report for the crash, there should be four columns of information with titles: Device, Operating System, Crash, and User.  The user ID will be on the far right under _User_.

Comment: @BobSnyder Not seeing this User section.

Comment: @UlisesGiacoman: Don't know.  Maybe the column is not shown if there is no user signed-in.

Comment: @BobSnyder I was testing my setup this morning. Looks like Crashlytics is currently experiencing crash processing delays. Going to check back later. Thanks for responding!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. There are three columns for Device, OS and Crash. But there is no column for "User".

Answer (score 6):

You can see it here:

[image]

Or try to search reports by user ID here:
[image]

If the search result is empty, it means your "test crash" hasn't synced yet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the user ID in Firebase Crashlytics because you are not calling the correct method.

Here is how to do it:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId("12345");
```

In addition, you can give yourself more context for the events leading up to a crash by logging custom message:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("Higgs-Boson detected! Bailing out");
```

For more infos:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?authuser=0&platform=android#set_user_ids

Answer (score 0):

Add                         `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId(uuid);`
in all screens (activities). If you add only in login screen then userid will not share to crashlytics, when app is crashed after reopening. Since we will ask user to login only once.